# vee-validate@next validationSchema function argument value always undefined

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a basic login form in Vue 3 that I am trying to validate using vee-validate@next composition api way. You can check it out at stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-zauhqb
But I am having issues...values that are injected to valiadtionSchema property functions are always undefined...
So first time the form is rendered, the value  of arguments in username and password validationSchema object functions are undefined (makes sense, there is no input), but even if I enter something and hit Submit, they are undefined.

Where is a problem with this code...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to this bug issue that I have posted on vee-validate git hub repo: https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/3658, you should call useForm() before any useField() calls...so after moving useField() below useForm() everything works as expected...